# Covering lemma used to prove Stone's lemma

Tags: geometry, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

So this is from the book "A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition". My question is with regards to the proof of Lemma 5.5. I don't understand why we can cover the unit spheres with points that satisfy $|x_i-x_j|\geq r$. Can someone please explain to me that step. I have included pages 66-68 from the book below. Also it seems the inequality isn't even true with $d=1$.

[Page 66](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LjYy.png)

[Page 67](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S78q3.png)

[Page 68](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3VQi.png)

Comment: Show that you can only pick a finite number of points $\{x_i\}$ on the unit sphere $S$ which are pairwise at least $r$ separated (this is usually a ratio of volumes argument). Now pick such a set $M$ with the additional constraint that it have maximum cardinality (this is well defined, since the card. is finite). If there is any point $y \in S$ that is not covered by $\bigcup_{x \in M} S_r(x) \cap S,$  then $ |y - x| \ge r$ for every $x \in M$, and thus $y \cup M$ is a bigger set with the $r$-separated property, contradicting the maximality of $M$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I took a look at the proof, and it is indeed iffy - to use the bounds they construct, it is necessary that $r/2 \le 1 - r/2 \iff r \le 1,$ (so that the balls of radius $r/2$ centered at $x_i$ and at $0$ don't intersect.) You can handle the $r>1$ case by instead inner bounding by $B(0, 1-r/2).$ Note that in applications the $-1$ is rarely relevant, and $r<1$ is usually the case. Also, for completeness' sake, the argument in my comment is non-constructive, and it can be quite non-trivial to find the optimal $r$-packing (as this is called).